# What happens if there are an equal number of votes?

Tags: conclave

In Conclave, when you are choosing the "direction" of your quest, you and your team need to vote.  The accepted choice will be the one with the majority of votes.

[image]

How is the option chosen if there is not a majority?

Comment: IIRC, it just goes with the last vote.  I cannot confirm this for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tie goes to the first voter.

[Source](http://forums.10x10room.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=963&p=1431&hilit=tie+votes#p1428)